# How to create wordpress tags synonym?

Tags: wordpress

How to create relationship between tags in word-press. For example, if someone clicks on UN or United Nations tag ,will get all the posts of both of the tags.

Comment: I am starting a plugin to make marking synonyms possible. If you have feedback on how you would like it to work, I am looking for ideas at https://github.com/lgedeon/term-synonyms

Answer (score 0):

Best to merge your tags (e.g. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-tags/) or use both.